# how to override Drupal deafult output contents of CCK field on new line

Tags: php, templates, drupal, field

I'm quite new to Drupal (using 7), but I've managed to set up my content types (e.g. `'concert'`) and I've created a `node-concert.tpl.php` whose HTML structure I need to rewrite to fit the information particular to the `concert` content type.

I have a wealth of CCK fields (almost all single-line text fields) in this content type, and I know how to access the contents of a field by using `<?php print render($content['field_fieldname']); ?>`. My problem is this: Drupal outputs every field on a new line. So, if I have the following fields with the following values:

```
field_concert_date = January 1, 2013
field_concert_time = 3 PM
field_concert_location = Boston, MA
```

Drupal will simply output each field value on a new line (all field labels are hidden). The output I want would go something like:

```
January 1, 2013 at 3PM in Boston, MA
```

I tried to achieve this by wrapping the output of all three fields in an `<h2>` tag, like so:

`<h2><?php print render($content['field_concert_date']); ?> at <?php print render($content['field_concert_time']); ?> in <?php print render($content['field_concert_location']); ?></h2>`

But Drupal still outputs everything (even the hard-coded text inside the `<h2>` tag) on its own line:

```
January 1, 2013
at
3 PM
in
Boston, MA
```

I've looked at [Customize a field output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835392/customize-a-field-output) and [Drupal: Print field without markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759856/drupal-print-field-without-markup) as well as done some basic Googling, but I can't quite find a reference to this **specific** problem. I'm assuming the culprit lies in some extra markup that is getting added somewhere that forces a new line at the end of every field, but I'm not entirely sure where it would be coming from. Is it in `field.tpl.php`? Or somewhere else? Or is it related to the call to `render()` (something that forces a line break after `render()` successfully returns the contents of a field)? Like I said, I'm fairly new to Drupal and haven't yet figured out how to pinpoint small-scale (but important!) problems like this.

Thanks!

An additional note: I'm in the process of creating a Drupal theme from scratch, and so far the only CSS I'm pulling in is a CSS Reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using text as the input format for those fields? Start there (/admin/structure/types/manage/[content_type]/fields).

Then check the **Manage Display** tab for the content type in question (/admin/structure/types/manage/[content_type]/display) and make sure you're using the **Plain Text** format.

Also check the **Filter processing order** for any filters that are enabled for the text format being applied to those fields, the screen's at /admin/config/content/formats.

Comment: Yes, text is the input format for all the fields, and they are all formatted to plain text. I was able to solve the problem by customizing `field.tpl.php` and getting rid of all the excess markup contained therein (three `div`s just to output a field!), leaving only the `<?php print render($item); ?>` inside the `foreach` loop. I'm not sure if that's the most sustainable solution, but it achieved what I wanted. If there are better solutions out there, I'd certainly appreciate hearing about them!

Comment: That's a solid sustainable solution. If it's your first Drupal template customization, congrats. You can do exciting things once you start working at the template level.